# Formatting invalid data from CSV file Python

Tags: python, csv, printing, formatting

for an assignment I need to validate a dataset (CSV file) that I got. It contains information of students: student number, first name, last name, date of birth, study program. I did that (checking for valid and invalid data) already, but for clarity, these are the requirements for that:

- Student number has this format: 7 digits, starting with 0 and second digit (from left) can be either 9 or 8. Example: 0212345 is not valid
- First name and last names, contains only alphabet.
- Date of birth has this format: YYYY-MM-DD. Days between 1 and 31, months between 1 and 12 and Years between 1960 and 2004.
- Study program can have one of these values: INF, TINF, CMD, AI.

Then I need to print the valid and corrupt lines in the following format:

```
### VALID LINES ###
0873226,Junette,Gurry,1987-12-05,CMD
0983960,Leoline,MacCaughen,1993-02-12,TINF

### CORRUPT LINES ###
0773226,Junette,Gur_ry,1995-12-05, => INVALID DATA: ['0773226', 'Gur_ry', '']
0795003,Edna,Douce,1957-06-23,INF => INVALID DATA: ['0795003', '1957-06-23']
```

Printing the valid lines works just fine, the problem I'm having is that I can't seem to print the invalid data from the corrupt lines correctly. I've been trying different things now for hours, but I cannot find a solution that works.
Is there anyone who can help me out? I'll provide my code and a piece of the CSV file here down below.

My code:

```
import os
import sys
from datetime import datetime

valid_lines = []
corrupt_lines = []
tmp = []

n = 1
def validate_data(line):
    global n
    nr = False
    fn = False
    ln = False
    date = False
    prog = False
    line2 = line
    line = line.split(",")
    # Checking if the student number meets the requirements
    try:
      if line[0][0] == "0" and len(line[0]) == 7:
        if line[0][1] == "9" or line[0][1] == "8":
            nr = True
        else:
            pass
      else:
             pass
    except:
            pass
    # Checking if the first name meets the requirements
    try:
        if line[1] == '':
            pass
        elif line[1].isalpha:
            fn = True
            # print(True)
        else:
            pass
    except:
            pass
    # Checking if the last name meets the requirements
    try:
        if line[2] == '':
            pass
        elif line[2].isalpha and line[2] != "123124" and "^" not in line[2]:
            ln = True
        else:
            pass
    except:
            pass
    # Checking if the the date meets the requirements
    format = "%Y-%m-%d"
    try:
        date = bool(datetime.strptime(line[3], format))
        if date == True:
          year, month, day = line[3].split("-")
          if int(year) >=1960 and int(year) <=2004:
             date = True
          else:
              date = False
              pass
        else:
            pass
    except ValueError:
        pass
    # Checking if the study program meets the requirements
    list = ["INF", "TINF", "CMD", "AI"]
    try:
        if line[4] in list:
            prog = True
        else:
            pass
    except ValueError:
          pass
    if nr == True and fn == True and ln == True and date == True and prog == True:
        valid_lines.append(line2)
    else:
        # Trying to create a list with the invalid data.
        corrupt_lines.append(line2)
        if nr == False:
            tmp.append(line[0])
        if fn == False:
            tmp.append(line[1])
        if ln == False:
            tmp.append(line[2])
        if date == False:
            tmp.append(line[3])
        if prog == False:
            tmp.append(line[4])
    return tmp

def main(csv_file):
    with open(os.path.join(sys.path[0], csv_file), newline='') as csv_file:
        # skip header line
        next(csv_file)

        for line in csv_file:
            validate_data(line.strip())

    print('### VALID LINES ###')
    print("\n".join(valid_lines))
    print('### CORRUPT LINES ###')
    print(" => INVALID DATA [] \n".join(corrupt_lines))

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    main('students.csv')
```

And a bit of the CSV file:

```
studentnumber,firstname,lastname,dateofbirth,studyprogram
0873226,Junette,Gurry,1987-12-05,CMD
0983960,Leoline,MacCaughen,1993-02-12,TINF
0875514,Derrik,Garnson,2007-06-23,CMD
0807295,Christy,Rodwell,1997-09-05,CMD
0844343,Frannie,555,1997-05-08,TINF
0798488,Darbie,Habbijam,1997-10-11,AI
0973065,Glory,McLernon,2007-07-20,AI
0803417,Selie,Gunter,1974-01-05,DS
0963866,Wyatan,Lidgey,1987-08-23,DS
0946101,Rubie,De Lorenzo,1972-01-20,CMD
0834576,Bendite,Jeenes,1974-12-10,DS
0982484,Terra,Eckert,1977-11-22,TINF
0755219,Jacky,Driuzzi,1980-07-27,CMD
0970338,Nariko,Blackley,2006-07-14,DS
0869610,,,,CMD
```

Thanks in advance, I really appreciate it!

Comment: would be nice if your variables bore intuitive names, don't you think?

Answer (score 0):

The one big problem is that you're using global variables and having validate_data update those.  While you can know which lines are bad, you cannot know what parts of them are bad.

I recommend a decent restructure:

- Get rid of the global variables and have validate_data return the parts of a line that are bad, if any.  You're kinda already doing that, but again you're using the global variable tmp which has unwanted side effects right now.
- Track the valid and invalid lines in your main function by using any bad data returned from validate_data to know if a line is bad.

Declare a local variable in validate_data, like `bad_data = []` and return that instead of tmp:

```py
...
bad_data = []
if nr == False:
    bad_data.append(line[0])
if fn == False:
    bad_data.append(line[1])
if ln == False:
    bad_data.append(line[2])
if date == False:
    bad_data.append(line[3])
if prog == False:
    bad_data.append(line[4])

return bad_data
```

Now you don't need to check if all the parts are True, just check for each invalid and update bad_data accordingly.  If bad_data is empty (`[]`) when validate_data returns, that means the line is valid.

Next, declare valid_lines and invalid_lines in main and update them in your line-loop based on what validate_data returns:

```py
def main(csv_file):
    valid_lines = []
    corrupt_lines = []
    
    ...
    
        for line in csv_file:
            line = line.strip()  # modify line to be its stripped self and use that going forward
            bad_data = validate_data(line)
            if bad_data:  # means if bad_data != []
                corrupt_lines.append(line + " => INVALID DATA [" + ", ".join(bad_data) + "]")
            else:
                valid_lines.append(line)
    
    ...
```